# Chrome Remote Developer tools not interpreting received data

Tags: node.js, websocket, google-chrome-devtools, remote-debugging

I'm trying to create a Google Chrome DevTools Remote debugging session.

I have a remote debugging session, running on this URL:

```
chrome-devtools://devtools/remote/serve_rev/@8925c3c45f3923bc78ffc841842183cc592a0143/inspector.html?ws=localhost:8888/5f3be6ad-c4dd-4835-baf6-99779b6de1f6&remoteFrontend=true&dockSide=unlocked&experiments=true
```

And I have a Node.js server, connected to remote DevTools via a Websocket connection.

I'm trying to send following message to the remote debugging session:

```
id: 1,
method: "Log.entryAdded",
params: {
   timestamp: (new Date).getTime(),
   text: "Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 47ms",
   source: "violation",
   level: "verbose",
}
```

The remote session clearly receives the message, judging from the Network log. (It's the last one)

[image]

But the dev tools don't seem to interpret the message correctly. As my Console is empty. But I'd expect a line, containing the a text message from above.

I'm stuck on this problem, as I don't know how to even debug this any further.

Help much aprreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to **somewhat** work this out.

I actually had to enable

```
{
   method: "Page.enable"
}
```

and

```
{
   method: "Page.getResourceTree"
}
```

in the debugger.

Now remote debugger correctly displays gathered console.log data. Therefore, enabling only

```
{
   method: "Log.enable"
}
```

does not seem to be enough. Remote debugger needs more data than this, to interpret console.log data.